# need help converting a ctx command to an interaction command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using the basic_voice.py example to help code my own music bot, for the options to play music they use   ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None),

I'm using slash commands though and am using interactions instead of ctx however when i do interactions.guild.voice_client I cant find a .play option

I looked through all of the options in pylance and the documentation but I have not been able to find an alternitive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the documentation, it appears that `guild.voice_client` returns `VoiceProtocol`, which doesn't have the `play()` method.

You could use something similar to the following to get the `VoiceClient` for the guild instead.

```
voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=interaction.guild)
```

This should return a `VoiceClient` instance from which you can run the `play()` method.